# Can an atom according to Bohr's model be considered a black body?

Tags: visible-light, atomic-physics, thermal-radiation

I recently read about Bohr's atomic model and found out that an atom tends to absorb all the energy of a particular frequency to excite its electron and it also gives the same amount of energy that it absorbed to the surroundings when coming back to ground state . Please explain in simple words.

Comment: not in the statistical definition of black body http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Bohr's model of atom introduces special states(orbits) and their energies, and associates line spectra with transitions between those states. It has nothing to do with black bodies; Bohr's model is not meant to explain  black bodies, and it does not have the main property of a black body - that black body  is a macroscopic body that absorbs radiation of all frequencies, and reflects nothing. Bohr's atom absorbs radiation only if its frequency is one of the allowed transition frequencies. Other radiation is not absorbed, it either goes through or is reflected.

Comment: Thank you very much